# PHP & AJAX Getting response but not loading new page

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hi am passing a username and password to a php page using AJAX, once it has identified the username and password exists I want to load the page main.html.

At the moment when i submit the form, i get the response true back, this shows above the form in the location of the error message label, but it doesn't load the main.html page.

I am newbie and so not really sure where i have gone wrong, I have run the code in the chrome web developer Console but it isn't showing any problems and was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.

URL to the page : http://goo.gl/7QGrnr

HTML Code

```
 <label id="errorMessage"></label>
 <form  name="login" class="login">
   <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
   <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
   <input type="submit" name="login" class="login" value="Login" id="orange"/>
 </form>
```

AJAX Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form.login').submit(function () {
    var username = $("[name='username']").val();
    var password = $("[name='password']").val()
    // ...
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  data: "username="+ username +"& password="+ password,
  success: function(response){
    if(response == 'true') {
          window.location.href='main.html';
        }
        else {
          $("#errorMessage").html(response);
        }   
      }
    });
return false;
  });
});
```

PHP Code

```
           $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
           $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

           if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
            {
           $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and  password ='5d503cf3064551d1bae24d5e2aaedbd9'");
           $num_rows01 = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($num_rows01 === 1)
            {
              echo 'true';
            }
              else
            {
              echo 'false';
            }
          }
```

Comment: If something is shown in `errorMessage` then definintely it's not `true`. `console.log(response)` and check what you received

Comment: MySQL functions are deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO. MD5 is almost not worth using anymore, you should use more modern hashing functions depending on your PHP version but look into Bcrypt. Now your problem, if you are seeing an error message div, then your response is not "true", console.log(response); in your success handler to find out what's going on. Chances are you either have a parse error in your PHP, or you need to set dataType: "text" in your Ajax call.

Comment: It is advisable to add an `error` section in your AJAX call. This way, you can, to some extent, see what might have gone wrong with your code. Use the following code after `success` function:
`error: function(xhr, status, error)
{
    console.log(error);
}`
Let me know what error are you getting here.

Comment: do you mean like this  success: function(response){
             error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(error); }
             if(response == 'true')

Answer (score 5):

This is a straight forward problem that can be easily solved if only you debug your JS properly. Let me teach you one simple technique. In your JS insert break points at all the important locations. The code stops at each break point and you can then see the state. In this case we have to be sure if the code enters the success scenario. We insert a break point like follows:

```
    success: function(response){
 debugger;
             if(response == 'true')
                    {
                         window.location.href='main.html';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#errorMessage").html(response);
                    }   
            }
```

if the code enters into success scenario it should hit the debugger. You can then see the state of each variable and locate the problem immediately. **This small technique will help you in the longer run, believe me!**

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, thats very handy, when i run the code, it stops at debugger, then when i go to next step it returns the word true and stops

Comment: So that means that if response is really true, the debugger should enter the if(response == 'true') block. Once it has entered there it will hit the line window.location.href='main.html';

Comment: So basically on the php page it is just echoing the output and displaying the word true but is not passing back to the javascript, i think

Comment: Ya that can be the case. But again it depends on your code. You must have put in a url in your ajax call. Kindly see if its accurate. Also see that the ajax call syntax is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return false I would use jQuery's

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in PHP from

```
echo 'true';
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array('response'=>'true'));
```

Change in Javascript from

```
function(response){
  if(response == 'true')
  {
    window.location.href='main.html';
  }
```

to

```
function(data){
  if(data.response == 'true')
  {
    window.location.href='main.html';
  }
  else
  {
    $("#errorMessage").html(data.response);
  }
```

Add datatype:'json' to ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  datatype: "json",
  data: "username="+ username +"& password="+ password,
```

change data: "username="+ username +"& password="+ password, to

```
data: {'username':username,'password':password},
```

Comment: Thanks I made that change and now it generates the error Uncaught Reference Eror: Response is not defined

Comment: I think you still have to add datatype:'json' to your ajax call

Comment: Thanks, ok, so that makes more sense, looking at some other tutorials, but now when i click submit i get nothing back and it doesn't flag an error in the console

Comment: What do you see in the console if you add console.log(data); direct under function(data){

Comment: Nothing, I added that bit of code, but as soon as i press the login button, i get nothing back not even in the consile

Comment: The PHP script is not returning anything. If you hardcode echo json_encode(array('response'=>'true')); to the bottom of the PHP script it will work.

Comment: What do you mean hardcode, do you mean to just add the code to the bottom of the php page?

Comment: Yes, just add it to the bottom of the PHP page. You should see something in your console now.

Comment: I just found another error in your code. Look at my edited answer for details.

Comment: Ok so i made that change, it seems like it doesn't even submit the form now as the values stay in the input fields when i click on the login button and nothing happens

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Did you get anything on your console?

Comment: No nothing, as i say now its behaving like the form isn't even submitting.  But thank you, i have a better understanding now, so will look at some more tutorials and see if i can work it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
location.reload();
```

instead of

```
 window.location.href='main.html';
```

Comment: His script isn't getting to that part, but even if it was - why would refreshing the current page be a better idea than redirecting to his desired destination?